# Anyway to hide row ID column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have some datagridviews on my form. They are for read only data. They are showing what normally would be the row count column. Is there anyway to remove this. Allowing for just the data I need to appear?

see image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8QLf.jpg "Example"

I have tired to look though the visual studio tools. I know i can hide rows that have data in them just not this one.

```
private void ViewAllOrders()
    {

        string productrselect = 
           @"SELECT Orders.order_ID as 'Order ID', 
                    V_Customer.Name as 'Customer', 
                    Orders.order_date as 'Order Date', 
                    orders.order_total as 'Order Total'
              FROM  V_Customer INNER JOIN
                    Orders ON V_Customer.[Customer ID] = Orders.customer_id
           ORDER BY order_id desc";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        var dataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(productrselect, con);
        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter2);
        var ds2 = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter2.Fill(ds2);
        dataGridViewOrderHistory.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridViewOrderHistory.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have highlighted in your image, it appears that you're talking about the row headers. You can hide these using `dataGridViewOrderHistory.RowHeadersVisible = false;` (or via the Properties window for your DataGridView).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @ChrisBirch - Glad I could help! Knowing is half the battle :)